# Prove that a sequence will reach $0$ before a certain point.

Tags: combinatorics

Both $n_1$ and $n_2$ are positive integers less than $10000$ .

For $ k ≥ 3$, define $n_k$ to be the
minimum value of $|n_i − n_j|$ for $1 ≤ i < j ≤ k − 1$.

Prove that $n_{21} = 0$

In order to have $n_{21} = 0$, there have to be at least 2 elements from ${n_1, n_2, ..., n_{20}}$ that are equal. Since clearly $n_k \geq n_{k+a}$ for positive integers $k,a$, we know if for some $x$,

$n_x = n_y$,

then $|x-y| = 1$.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like any sequence of this sort with $n_k \neq 0$ must have $n_1 \geq F_k$ or $n_2 \geq F_k$ where $F_k$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: This is related to the number of steps required to find a gcd via the Euclidean algorithm, and in that setting has been asked and answered on this site many times.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you point me in some of the questions with that?

Comment: I have given you some search terms. You can use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We make the following claim:

**Lemma** : Let $n_1,n_2 < F_k$ be positive integers, where $F_k$ is the kth Fibonacci number. Then, $n_k=0$.

**Proof** : We prove by strong induction. The cases $k=1,2,3$ are trivial to check. Now, assume that the claim is true for $k$. Now, we show that it is true for $k+1$. WLOG, assume $n_1 \leqslant n_2$. Then, $n_1 + n_3 = n_2$. We know that $n_1,n_2 < F_{k+1}$. We now analyze a few cases:

**Case 1** : $F_k \leqslant n_1$. Here, $n_3 < F_{k+1}-F_k = F_{k-1}$. We can see that $n_4 \leqslant n_3$ since $n_4 \leqslant |n_1-n_2|$, and hence, $n_4 < F_{k-1}$. Now, we can apply induction with $n_3$ and $n_4$ replacing $n_1$ and $n_2$, and $k+1$ replaced by $k-1$.

**Case 2** : $n_1 < F_k \leqslant n_3$. Here, apply the first case with $n_1$ and $n_3$ swapped.

**Case 3** : $n_1,n_3 < F_k$. Here, apply induction with $n_1$ and $n_3$ replacing $n_1$ and $n_2$, and $k+1$ replaced by $k$.

Thus, the lemma is true. Now, simply use the fact that $F_{21} > 10000$.